# How to filter a pandas data frame with respect to a substring inside a field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring, filtering

I'm tryng to filter a pandas dataframe with a date field, in string format, and I would like to filter by a specific part of the date.

I tried to use the usual dataframe way with:

```
filtered_shops = shops[shops['opening'][-2:] != "22"]
```

And then I get the following error: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

I managed to solve my issue using `filtered_shops = shops[shops['opening'].str.endswith('22') == False]`, but it seems over complicated for such a simple filtering. I would like to know a generic method that would allow me to filter with any substring (not just the prefix or suffix). I also know that the method I used can take (start, end) parameters and therefore find any substring inside the field but I'm looking for a more straighforward solution because I think it might just be a silly error in my first try.

Comment: If you're looking for a "cleaner" method, then why not convert the string to a "real" datetime object and then use a more pythonic syntax like `shops['opening'].dt.hour != 22`? I'm assuming you're trying to test against the opening hour of your date string. This way you will be sure you're handling the right type. Otherwise, if you're handling normal strings, regex is going to provide you the only solution: the `endswith` method is just a special application of regex filtering.

Comment: What is the current column format, e.g. dd-MM-YY HH:mm:ss ?

Comment: `filtered_shops = shops[~shops['opening'].str.endswith('22')]` is more elegant btw

Comment: The current format is dd-MM-YY

Comment: Thanks for the tips for "real" datetime object, I didn't know it existed. So I can not slice the string inside the date field when filtering? I'm not sure to understand what the error means.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you're looking for how to search if the string contains another string.

```
filtered_shops = shops[shops['opening'].str.contains('22') == False]
```

Comment: This method would find any `'22'` inside the column, so not exactly the functionality I'm looking for. I would like to find instances of 22 in a specific substring of the column. For example: 22-01-21 ⇾ is 2021, and I check the last 2 digits for that, your solution would filter way too many dates.

Answer (score 0):

To check inside some (beginning, end) range you can use:

```py
def apply_substr_filter(df, substr, col, start=0, end=None):
    return df[df[col].str.slice(start, end).str.contains(substr)]
```

which you could use to check an endswith:

```py
apply_substr_filter(shops, '22', 'opening', start=-2, end=None)
```